# Is self-centered talk an ADHD symptom?

Tags: adhd

I have noticed a man I know well whom I strongly suspect suffers from ADHD turning discussion about his activities too often. He can discuss in detail what he did during the day and why, even when that is of limited interest to his audience.

I can find a commercial website [suggesting](https://www.additudemag.com/adhd-listening-problems/) that ADHD causes one to excessively talk about oneself, and considerable [anecdotal evidence](https://www.reddit.com/r/adhdwomen/comments/hgw4sv/talking_too_much_about_yourself/), but nothing authoritative.

Is there strong evidence that **ADHD causes excessive self-centered talk?**

Answer (score 1):

There are individual differences but many studies suggest a correlation between deficiencies in the frontal lobe and endowing ADHD. The frontal lobe consists of PFC (there are also studies suggesting that self-representation can be handled in the MPFC and dlPFC which could explain your hypothesis, [here](https://www.cell.com/neuron/fulltext/S0896-6273(06)00212-1?_returnURL=https%3A%2F%2Flinkinghub.elsevier.com%2Fretrieve%2Fpii%2FS0896627306002121%3Fshowall%3Dtrue)!, OFC ([threatened social responses](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S027826260300277X),) and ACC ([which handles with switching attention between tasks.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1053811904003234))

You can read more about it here:
https://www.academia.edu/13582990/Frontal_lobe_functions_in_attention_deficit_disorder_with_and_without_hyperactivity_A_review_and_research_report

Also, here is a study on rats where HI rats are more egocentric.

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11055-020-01018-6